# git show a patch for a merge commit

Tags: git

Lets say I have the following merge commit

```
commit e1370b76cb1a8e3e00b4770038fed678eb085731
Merge: cb5a2fa 8c596d8
Author: Chris Muench <chris@phppointofsale.com>
Date:   Thu Oct 1 16:09:08 2015 -0400

    Merge remote-tracking branch 'vijay/15.0_dev' into 15.0_dev
```

If I do git show `e1370b76cb1a8e3e00b4770038fed678eb085731` it doesn't show any changes.

Is `git diff cb5a2fa 8c596d8` always going to be the best way? What happens if there was a conflict in the merge; will that work?

I know how to get a diff BEFORE I merge a remote (`git diff ...remote/branch`); but I want to be able to see it AFTER I merge.

Comment: "Is git diff cb5a2fa 8c596d8 always going to be the best way? What happens if there was a conflict in the merge; will that work?" -- As answered in the other question, but perhaps not clear directly: no, but `git diff cb5a2fa e1370b7` or equivalently `git diff e1370b7^ e1370b7` will. In fact, you can (in bash) even write it as `git diff e1370b7{^,}`.